# Cassandra RackInferringSnitch datacenter name

Tags: cassandra

The rack inferring snitch uses the 2nd octet as the datacenter, and the third as the rack. When using NetworkTopologyStrategy for replication, do people actually use a number as the datacenter name? e.g. if an ip is 10.222.200.54, would a table creation look like this:

```
create table blah (id int primary key, foo text) 
with replication={'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', '222':3 }
```

Is this common? Or is there a way to alias the '222' component? Or is the RackInferringSnitch not really used? Should we stick to gossipping property file snitch?

Answer (score 3):

I think this snitch is meant as an example of how to write a custom snitch. I don't think it's intended to be used in production.

http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/architecture/architectureSnitchRackInf_c.html

Comment: Yes...I read the documentation...wondering if anybody's actually gone ahead and done it. I can see it making certain things simpler for our overburdened admins :)

Comment: Really? I don't see evidence of that. I think they supply it so that, if it makes sense for your use case, you can easily use it with minimal administrative load. If it doesn't work for you, use one of the others.